# our angular application isn't working from IOS 15 (Safari) , it works for older versions of safari and other browsers

Tags: ios, angular, safari, widget

Application is not loading in safari 15 and higher versions, there are no console errors.

In chrome our application is being detected as angular application and the component is loaded as  Angular widget component here

Where as in safari it is loaded as 
Screenshots attached.

Source code:

```
<script>
    var angWidgets = 'unauthenticated';
    var cId = '@ViewBag.ClientId';
</script>
@{string angWidgetsHtml = "<unauthenticated></unauthenticated>";}
<app></app>
<script>
    var angWidgetsHtml = "@Html.Raw(angWidgetsHtml)";
</script>
```

[Inspect source code image in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnBrm.png)

[Inspect source code image in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlBF3.png)

Comment: Seems that your using a framework on top of Angular. Which one is that?

Comment: we are using MVC(.Net framework) with angular, View in MVC calls the angular component.